# How to Import JSON data to typescript Map<K, V> type?

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to import json data that might include present or absent mappings within one of the properties, and figured the correct data type to represent this was `Map<string, number>`, but I'm getting an error when I try to do this.

My JSON file, data.json, looks like this:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "name":"test1",
            "config":"origin",
            "entries": {
                "red":1,
                "green":2
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "name":"test2",
            "config":"remote",
            "entries": {
                "red":1,
                "blue":3
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "name":"test3",
            "entries": {
                "red":1,
                "blue":3,
                "purple":3
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My typescript code, Data.ts, which attempts to read it looks like this:

```
import data from './data.json';

export class Data {
    public name:string;
    public config:string;
    public entries:Map<string, number>;
    constructor(
        name:string,
        entries:Map<string, number>,
        config?:string
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.entries = entries;
        this.config = config ?? "origin";
    }
}

export class DataManager {
    public datas:Data[] = data.datas;
}
```

But that last line, `public datas:Data[] = data.datas;`, is throwing an error.

Is there a proper way to import data like this?

The goal, ultimately, is to achieve three things:

1. Any time `entries` is present, it should receive *some* validation that it only contains properties of type `number`; what those properties are is unknown to the programmer, but will be relevant to the end-user.
2. If `config` is absent in the JSON file, the construction of `Data` objects should supply a default value (here, it's "origin")
3. This assignment of the data should occur with as little boilerplate code as possible. If, down the line `Data` is updated to have a new property (and Data.json might or might not receive updates to its data to correspond), I don't want to have to change how `DataManager.data` receives the values

Is this possible, and if so, what's the correct way to write code that will do this?

Comment: A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) holds key-value pairs but it is not a plain JS object. It's not clear to me why you want to use `Map` or even your `Data` class, but you need to *convert* from json to an array of `Data` yourself if you want to do that.  Perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP7d5m).  Does that meet your needs? Please test. If so, I can write up an answer. If not, what am I missing? I'm a bit concerned that you're going to go one step past this and realize you're not happy with `Data`/`Map` after all.

Comment: @jcalz That's a little overly dramatic, lol. This is obviously a reduced test case of what I'm actually trying to do. The solution you provided seems to work, but given the actual object contains a lot more [known, definitely present] properties, this solution creates a lot of boilerplate code (i.e. manually typing each property name) which isn't ideal. Is there a version of this that won't require me to change this mapping if `Data` gains more properties that aren't in the `entries` property?

Comment: I wasn't trying to be dramatic so let me try again. You have a `class` named `Data` where the only way to get an instance of it is to write `new Data(n, e)` for suitable `n` and `e` values. So if you want to use it, you need to write `new Data(d.name, d.entries.map(xxx))`. That constructor is in the example code, so if you don't like having to type those properties in one by one, then that's a problem with the class itself. Do you maybe not want to use a class at all? Do you understand/appreciate the difference between a `class` and an `interface`?

Comment: The part that seems to be the topic of the question is mostly writing `new Map(Object.entries(d.entries))` to convert from a plain object (`d.entries`) to a `Map` with the same keys and values.  If you're okay with that part, then we should focus on that, and the class constructor thing is just a distraction. But I'm not sure you're really okay with that part (again, not being dramatic, just trying to understand your intent). Most people would prefer writing `e.purple` instead of `e.get("purple")` or `e.green++` instead of `e.set("green",e.get("green")+1)`, so I'm skeptical.

Comment: @jcalz Omitting the constructor might be an option, but I do want [some of] the properties to receive default values if they aren't specified by the JSON feeding them. I don't think using `Map` in this context is incredibly critical, but there are some constraints on `entries`, i.e. it's never [supposed to be] containing nested objects. So an ideal solution lets me 1. assign default values to properties that are missing, and 2. applies *some* type-checking to `entries` (i.e. validates it contains properties whose values are only numbers) while 3. doesn't have tons of boilerplate code.

Comment: @jcalz A solution that does those three things is what I'm looking for, irrespective of whether I actually use the literal `Map` type or not; irrespective of whether my constructor is defined exactly the way I wrote it in the code sample.

Comment: "but I do want [some of] the properties to receive default values if they aren't specified by the JSON feeding them." Hmm, but the constructor doesn't do that; if you call `new Data()` without arguments, you will get `undefined` data (at runtime) and a compiler error (at compile time). It helps when example code is a [mre] where people don't have to selectively ignore pieces of it. It sounds like your actual goal is to solve your 1,2,3 list, so maybe you should [edit] the question to spell that out and give a genuine example including things you want to accept/reject.

Comment: @jcalz Well, yes: the code was pared down to just the elements that would reliably reproduce the error message I was getting. The real constructor has actual validation of some of the inputs. I'll edit in a more complex example and said list of priorities in terms of what the correct code should do.

Comment: So then is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlgBxw) better for your needs? I'm not using a `Map` for the entries; instead I'm using a plain object with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  And I'm not using a `class` for the data type; instead I'm using an `interface`.  This should meet 1,2,and 3, although for 1 it's just filtering instead of some other "validation" (e.g., throw a big error or something?) Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz That seems like it'll work. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightest weight approach to this would not be to create or use [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) for your data. You can instead use plain JavaScript objects, and just describe their types strongly enough for your use cases.  So instead of a `Data` class, you can have an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), and instead of using [instances of the `Map` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with `string`-valued keys, you can just use a plain object with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to represent the type of data you already have:

```
interface Data {
    name: string;
    config: string;
    entries: { [k: string]: number }
}
```

To make a valid `Data`, you don't need to use `new` anywhere; just make an object literal with `name`, `config`, and `entries` properties of the right types.  The `entries` property is `{ [k: string]: number }`, which means that you don't know or care what the keys are (other than the fact that they are `string`s as opposed to `symbol`s), but the property values at those keys should be `number`s.

---

Armed with that definition, let's convert `data.datas` to `Data[]` in a way that meets your three criteria:

```
const datas: Data[] = data.datas.map(d => ({
    config: "origin", // any default values you want
    ...d, // the object    
    entries: onlyNumberValues(d.entries ?? {}) // filter out non-numeric entries
}));

function onlyNumberValues(x: { [k: string]: unknown }): { [k: string]: number } {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(x).filter(
            (kv): kv is [string, number] => typeof kv[1] === "number"
        )
    );
}
```

1. The above sets the `entries` property to be a filtered version of the `entries` property in the incoming data, if it exists.  (If `entries` does not exist, we use an empty object `{}`).  The filter function is `onlyNumberValues()`, which breaks the object into its entries via [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), filters these entries with a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), and packages them back into an object via [the `Object.fromEntries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).  The details of this function's implementation can be changed, but the idea is that you perform whatever validation/transformation you need here.
2. Any required property that may be absent in the JSON file should be given a default value. We do this by creating an object literal that starts with these default properties, after which we [spread in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#spread_properties) the properties from the JSON object. We do this with the `config` property above. If the JSON object has a `config` property, it will overwrite the default when spread in.  (At the very end we add in the `entries` property explicitly, to overwrite the value in the object with the filtered version).
3. Because we've spread the JSON object in, any properties added to the JSON object will automatically be added.  Just remember to specify any defaults for these new properties, if they are required.

Let's make sure this works as desired:

```
console.log(datas)

/* [{
  "config": "origin",
  "name": "test1",
  "entries": {
    "red": 1,
    "green": 2
  }
}, {
  "config": "remote",
  "name": "test2",
  "entries": {
    "red": 1,
    "blue": 3
  }
}, {
  "config": "origin",
  "name": "test3",
  "entries": {
    "red": 1,
    "blue": 3,
    "purple": 3
  }
}] */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAsAKBvmAIkWQkIC4YBtXAuzW+pwsBAWwFMKioPoBGQgBpGTOoVBgAZgEsA5t0IgATvJlhhosfkIcwUVX27Y82sYWUc43fiNNn6hOZb3cATFu0BfTwR-36O20TBx1WTkVeaDdNAO0JcFkFSgsONhBeWNCiPQMZI0oQ7IJU60pbXwdCACMAGwBXLkoAZkr6f282oLEiqvCmnj4oZqzQ3X1DMkK2+MsymAq4sbrG7mbu4qIAB3rlLdqB9ZnzAE8OWtqQAHdFAHUACQBBZ8eAfgBCQhgAem+YAB4ALSAmAgEBbCDHfAdMQw-AAXVw-lw6l4yikCGAHBgABEkChejB+pRoKowHIANxaSRJEl5clUgK5SaFagAazpZLk8MoYHqbGqHGUMH8yJwkmg8HxEEoeOQVHhaClyAAdCQEBAVWwEFsABRwNAAPhgusJNPkKRUag0Qh+fwQYBO8A4GPqtVgADcEA0+DATiB6jArg6oFoVeG4LbfjAoAALbEgaoAKw4wFgBC0zPyMtBYFqJwAcvzBcoAGrexoQfUqrO+16vTBeACUdpgsndQtB9VgYHAgL5nFUwBgtYgMHjliRTabjNwUnqYDTMnAufzRYFQvLPqrAA9WVQOTBSepuZQF2ze1cwCKm-vD8fyTyicXO14GAFLFBdteAPLJ1NQCqUjKCAbAAKITNmuptH+KZpjWkF8LqO5NkBMgdso0FLEwupsh6t4wHhMAyGOVAPnItoDiWiqoMaUAnFsHAgFIhEelQ-A0ag6AsC+yiEG0TZaDOSK4LgEogAcKqXHI+rSoJOC4N8ABU1BFAk0jyIoVpyOoowsOwAyEFEUCCN04x5AU77iHMNgbEQzgcK4lAeKYoq2mp5rJEQljpJkZn9JEQwxGZo7GFopS2eFKyHIwblWUQnlaaoOk2ow+kRCkxkjCFiFTPFOg2eUdk1D6azFTsewHGssVIoqSnfKJOBAA)